# Animation / Transition fullscreen button parent and make parent siblings slide to the side and disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-transitions

**What I am trying to do:**
I am trying to animate 3 divs containing 1 button each. When one of those buttons is clicked, I want the div containing it to slide to fullscreen and the other two, that is, the siblings of the parent, to slide to 0% width and disappear, as a nice, good looking animation.

**What isn't working:**
It seems I cannot make the animation seem fluid, the two disappearing elements gives me a lot of problem, mostly because the 0% width transition isn't working out for me.

I have made a fiddle containing my problem, and am interested in making this transition / animation as fluid as possible.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="testpile" class="inner cover">
  <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
    <div class="col-md-4 rat">
      <h1>Rationelt</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
      <button id="1" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Personligt</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 emo">
      <h1>Emotionelt</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
      <button id="2" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Personligt</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 per">
      <h1>Personligt</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
      <button id="3" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Personligt</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('fullscreen');
  $(this).parent().siblings().toggleClass('mast1');
  $(this).parent().siblings().fadeOut(250, function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().css({
      "visibility": "hidden",
      display: 'block'
    });
  });
});
```

[Fiddle for animation](https://jsfiddle.net/77k8rrrm/3/)

I would prefer no position: absolute;, as it tends to mess up the rest of my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed this part from your js

```
$(this).parent().siblings().fadeOut(250, function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().css({
      "visibility": "hidden",
      display: 'block'
    });
  });
```

I don't know why you added it or what was it doing? so your js is here:

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('fullscreen');
  $(this).parent().siblings().toggleClass('mast1');
});
```

and added `overflow:hidden` to `.mast1`

```
.mast1 {
  width: 0%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/77k8rrrm/4/

Comment: Ah, that does solve my problem. But I can then not have any padding on the divs, can I? How would I go about that? Also, it kinda annoys me that you fixed it that quick, hah, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. and about your question did you mean padding for those divs ( .rat .emo and .per ), and please tell me if you are using bootstrap or not

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not specify my question very well. Yes, I meant for the divs ( .rat, .emo and .per ) and yes, I am using bootstrap, I should have specified that in my original question too.

Comment: in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/77k8rrrm/5/ I added bootstrap files and made small edit to the css .mast1 . see it and I hope that is what you want

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and time, my problem is solved now.